# getting incoming imageUri null from an chooser intent

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to access the image from whats app on sharing the image content. so i have already written code for chooser intent in android manifest. now to handle the incoming image i wrote code like below

```
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityStartedEvent, function (args) {

    console.log("Event: " + args.eventName + ", Activity: " + args.activity);
// Event: activityStarted, Activity: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity@8a3b9cc


    let intent = args.activity.getIntent();
    let action = intent.getAction();
    let type = intent.getType();

    console.log(intent);
//Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/* flg=0x1b080001 cmp=org.myapp.new_app/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity clip={image/* U:content://com.whatsapp.fileprovider/external/WhatsApp/.Shared/photo.jpg} (has extras) }

    console.log(action);
//android.intent.action.SEND

    console.log(type);
// image/*

    let imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    console.log(imageUri);
//null

}
```

I expect the output not to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log already shows you what exactly you have to read from intent (clip).

```
intent.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri()
```

Comment: i dont know why it is in short form like act for action, typ for type. i'm sure its not a javascript concept. so i didn't get how to read that data.